# Custom permalink option not works, custom structure ignored and post-name used

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

At `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` of a domain root  with Wordpress  (and *no* `.htaccess`), the first option, that is the standard option, is working, `http://www.example.com/?p=123`

So I think that is possible to reproduce (only to reproduce) exactly the same thing at the custom option... I try  `/?p=%post_id%`, `?p=%post_id%`  and many other and always the effect is navigation as `/post-name/` not `?p=id` ... So, is not working?  What exactly I need to copy/paste in the form box of "Custom structure" option?

I am using new wordpress, v4.4

PS: no clues at https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen

---

#### NOTES

Why?

Because "Custom permalink" is not working.... Or, in fact, it NOT WORKS on Wordpress?

It is a technical proof, when working I can do anything. 
Example: need for hash, `?p=%post_id%#post-%post_id%` is so important, for jump *slide show*, and scrool to page title.

In this example the problem is not a kind of Apache permission or *rewrite mode*, the `?p=123#post-123` works fine (!) in any context, therefore, Wordpress must comply with the required "Custom permalink".

Comment: Why can't you just use the "Default" structure?

Comment: @mevius It is a technical proof, if works I can do anything. Example: `, ?p=%post_id%#%post_id%` is so imprtant, for jump slider and show page title.

Comment: may be ur mod rewrite rule is not enabled

Comment: @ujwaldhakal Yes, is not, "no `.htaccess`", but there are no demand of  *mod rewrite* in `?p=%post_id%#%post_id%` (!).

Comment: no demand? if your mod rewrite wont enable then you cnt get custom url :) why dont you turn it on ? you on linux or windows?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal  ok, I like *mod rewrite*  but in some cases we can't use it, but Wordpress *must work*  even in that context.

Comment: how can apache parse your permalinks custom if u didnt give him permission to enable parse

Comment: @ujwaldhakal See my EDIT, and please understand that HTTP, PHP and Apache not need *rewrite mod* to work with a *query string*, as `?p=123`  or `?p=123#post-123`.

Comment: @PeterKrauss the issue is which parameters are recognised by wp which are what you see on screen(more or less) , category, time etc. But this is how wp recognises patterns rather than what you can actually append to the url. the # is ignored by wp but not the browser so you can append your links (try a custom nav walker & post meta) to identify posts where you want to link by id, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting question, but almost everything you want isn't possible.

1. Use %post_id% twice:

   In `wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php`, at line 558 (WP 4.4) we have a for-loop that breaks if `%post_id%` was already found and used. The code is:

   ```
   preg_match_all('/%.+?%/', $this->permalink_structure, $tokens);
   $tok_index = 1;
   foreach ( (array) $tokens[0] as $token) {
       if ( '%post_id%' == $token && ($tok_index <= 3) ) {
           $front = $front . 'date/';
           break;
       }
       $tok_index++;
   }
   ```
2. Using '#':

   In `wp-admin/options-permalink.php`, when wp is saving the user input we have this line of code:

   ```
   $permalink_structure = preg_replace( '#/+#', '/', '/' . str_replace( '#', '', $permalink_structure ) );
   ```

   That `str_replace` makes impossible using `#' char.
3. The purpose of that screen:

   Wordpress uses that configuration screen for (1) give user the option of using pretty links or not and (2) give user the chance to choose how will be his **posts** permalink structure. Worpress itself handles a lot of rewrite rules that is not possible changing, unless you use it's [url rewrite functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule). Pages and custom posts, for instance, are handled differently.

You can try adding `/index.php?p=%post_id&var=%post_id%` as custom structure to see the magic (not) happening, but remember: it just works for posts.

Hope it helps.